# mysql large query not responding

Tags: mysql, sql, database

we have table with around 9 hundred thousand records.
we are trying to execute a query with having large data (NOTE: the query is large )

```
like <some query> and agt.item in (',productRange,.......<very large data, having around 2 lakh chars>)
```

with this the query is failing saying syntax error. but with less number of items in query it executes.
Please let me know how to handle this kind of issues.

Comment: I had to google what a lakh it, it's 100,000 for those wondering. Anyway, is it timing out before receiving the whole query?

Comment: No disrespect but I edited lakh as I think *hundred thousand* is more widely understood.

Comment: its not timing out but saying syntax error but removing some items it works fine. I want to understand how to handle this kind of queries having large data in the query

Comment: take a look into those removed items making query works fine and see if there is any SQL keyword or special character like **( ) ,** in it

Comment: Splitting those large items into two parts and executing two queries, both are executing fine.

Comment: I take it that it is a large list of many items in the IN clause, rather than a short list of large items? Assuming it isn't failing due to not being properly escaped I would be tempted to insert the list into a temporary table and then use a JOIN instead of using IN.

Comment: Are you trying to run this query from a higher level language (e.g. PHP), or from a external tool, or directly from the command-line?

Answer (score 3):

Most DBMS works terrible with large parameter lists.
So if you have a large "IN" list, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM   foo
WHERE  bar IN ('1','2','3','4'...,'500000')
```

you will get very poor performance compared with having a table containing all values you want to select on, and joining the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE baz (
    bar VARCHAR
)

INSERT INTO baz(bar) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO baz(bar) VALUES ('2');
INSERT INTO baz(bar) VALUES ('3');
INSERT INTO baz(bar) VALUES ('4');
...
INSERT INTO baz(bar) VALUES ('500000');

SELECT *
FROM   foo,
       baz
WHERE  foo.bar = baz.bar
```

So, as MySQL does not have table valued parameters your best bet is to store the data in a temp table instead of typing it out in the query, and don't forget you will need an index on the value you are filtering on (agt.item in your case).

Comment: @Raad, thanks for the elaborating edit. Such substantial contribution usually is usually created as a separate answer where you can receive upvotes for your contribution.

Comment: Yeah, well you got there first with the core reasoning - I just embellished a bit. Despite appearances, I'm not a total rep-whore =)

Answer (score 0):

If the valuesitemsitems inside your `IN` clause come from another previous query, then you might just use a subquery.

Assuming your current code looks like this:

```
SELECT some_field FROM table1 WHERE condition1;
-- returns a long list and/or large strings

SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE condition2 AND item IN ( @records_from_previous_query );
```

You could just rewrite it as:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2
JOIN table1 ON (table1.some_field = table2.item AND condition1)
WHERE condition2
```